# Get all possible configurable product SKU's and option SKU's from Magento Database

Tags: mysql, excel, magento, quickbooks

I'm not a coder (just a script fiddler) and I've got a particular problem with Magento that I cannot explain in terms of code or data, so I need to explain the situation. 
I sell configurable products that come in an array of options.  These are furniture products that use various codes that describe the final SKU of the product.  I've never fully written or listed every possible SKU outside of any e-commerce product I've used, but always used the in-app options, in Magento's case, custom options, to create an SKU as the customer orders the product.

Now I'm facing a nightmare as I'm finally getting a QuickBooks solution mapped out for our company, but I need to get a file with every possible SKU# to import into QB, so that we can use a download routine (ecc) to grab all the orders from Magento and pop them into QB without having to create each new product on the fly.  Each one of my products has the following choices:

- BaseSKU#
- FinishColorSKU#
- FabricComboSKU#
- FabricColorSKU#

So, for instance, I sell a chair.  The chair's base SKU# is 708.  The chair comes in 7 finishes, each with it's own code, so now I have 7 SKU's.  Each chair+finish comes in 5 fabric combination styles.  Not actual fabric, just the way it's applied to the chair.  So 7*5=35 is no problem.  Now it starts to get tricky.  2 of those fabric combo styles use only 1 fabric.  We have 60 fabrics.  35*60=2100.  At this point, this is not impossible to create in excel, a bunch of copying and pasting, but it can be done.  Now the other three fabric combo styles use 2 fabrics.  I need to create a SKU for every possible combination of fabric.  So 60*60=3600 possible combinations of the fabrics alone.  Now combine that with 35 different chair+finish combo, that's 126,000 possible SKU's for one product.  Multiply that times 300 products, there is no way I could do this by hand in Excel. The final SKU looks like these:

One color chair:
708-117-SC-5708

Chair708+Frame117+SingleColor+Color5708

Two color chair:
708-117-DC-5708-5709

Chair708+Frame117+DualColor+Color5708+Color5709

Now, since these possible combinations exist in the Magento Database, just not combined, is there any way to programmatically create all possible combinations and lump them into an Excel file, or csv, or ANYTHING?  Is this possible in Excel?  Maybe I just need to download the database, export the right table to Excel and do it there.

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:  Was thinking about this, and maybe the simplest way to ask this question would be:

How to make Magento output a list of all possible products and options?

Comment: I would think that this would be pretty simple to do in Excel using VBA.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - I agree with you, however, searching all the excel forums for this does provide a lot of info, but like I said, I'm not much of a coder, and VBA is still a bit of white man's voodoo to me. I just don't know enough about VB to construct the string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the export functionnality: *System -> export/import -> dataflow - profiles -> Export All Products*. It's pretty straight-forward to use, but feel free to ask if you need more help.

Comment: I've done that, and this has not given me all possible sku's as I've illustrated.  Also, I don't follow your navigation.  Unless you mean System > Import/Export > Profiles > Export All Products

Comment: Nope, that export does not give me all "possible" products, indluding the option sku's as I illustrated above.  But thanks for the input.